If statement always outputs the same thing
Whenever I input paper the output should say 2 but it outputs 1 and whenever I input scissors the output should be 3 but it outputs 1

import time #I'm gonna use this later

Choice = input("Rock, Paper or scissors: ")



if Choice == "rock" or "Rock":

    Choice = 1

    print(Choice)

elif Choice == "paper" or "Paper":

    Choice = 2

    print(Choice)

elif Choice == "scissors" or "Scissors":

    Choice = 3

    print(Choice)

else:

    print("Say Rock, Paper or Scissors")

I've tried to search up my problem but I can't find a solution

if Choice == "rock" or "Rock" is not doing what you think.

user23970414, the problem lies in the statement if Choice == "rock" or "Rock".  This evaluates to if (Choice == 'Rock') or 'Rock'.  Which in the case of  'scissors' evaluates to (choice == 'scissors) or 'Rock', reducing further equals (False or True).   This is why you get 'rock'.  A better approach is to use parentheses ie If  (Choice == "rock") or (Choice == "Rock).
